# Calling subprocess.call(...) yields in error "[WinError 2] System can't find the specified file"

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

Hello my dear educated programmers,

I am trying to execute a command in the cmd prompt using Python. My research showed, that the *subprocess* module should give me what I need.

However, when using even the most basic test cases, Python always shows the error "*[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified*". I have checked, that *subprocess.py* is where it's supposed to be and there's no problems importing. There are loads of other questions on StackOverflow, but all of the which I read were about a specific file actually missing or some problems with setting correct paths, etc..

In my case though, I get this error even when testing things like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("dir")
```

Any hints or tips what I could do wrong? I tried opening the cmd prompt as an admin, no luck still.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "dir" is a shell (cmd.exe) built-in command. Try adding `shell=True` as a parameter to `subprocess.call`

Comment: @AndyBrown Thank you! Originally I tried this from the python console in Spyder from the Anaconda Navigator and 
    shell=True
did not make a difference there, so when I went over to try this within the CMD prompt, somehow I discarded this parameter altogether..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following in Windows 10 command prompt

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("dir", shell=True)
```

Works fine. What OS/Python version are you using?

Comment: You're correct, @AndyBrown advised me to use `shell=True` in his comment as well. 
@mikeg Now this works! My problem was that I'm coming from MATLAB and I am hence so prone to working with the integrated command window of any IDE, so I typed all of this into Spyder's IPython console. When trying it out in the CMD shell, I was so annoyed because nothing would work, that I ditched the shell=True altogether, where it was actually supposed to be used..

Still struggling getting my head out of the MATLAB way of "programming"

Comment: How about `os.listdir()`. It will run on more machines than just Windows. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir